# Running scripts from another directory

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, script

Quite often, the script I want to execute is not located in my current working directory and I don't really want to leave it.

Is it a good practice to run scripts (BASH, Perl etc.) from another directory? Will they usually find all the stuff they need to run properly?

If so, what is the best way to run a "distant" script? Is it

```
. /path/to/script
```

or

```
sh /path/to/script
```

and how to use `sudo` in such cases? This, for example, doesn't work:

```
sudo . /path/to/script
```

Comment: Be aware that `. /path/to/script` **sources** the script! You don't need the period at all if you just want to run it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

sh /path/to/script will spawn a new shell and run she script independent of your current shell. The `source` (.) command will call all the commands in the script in the current shell. If the script happens to call `exit` for example, then you'll lose the current shell. Because of this it is usually safer to call scripts in a separate shell with sh or to execute them as binaries using either the full (starting with `/`) or relative path (`./`). If called as binaries, they will be executed with the specified interpreter (`#!/bin/bash`, for example).

As for knowing whether or not a script will find the files it needs, there is no good answer, other than looking at the script to see what it does. As an option, you could always go to the script's folder in a sub-process without leaving your current folder:

```
(cd /wherever/ ; sh script.sh)
```

Comment: Do you mean `(cd /wherever/ ; sh script.sh)`?  Why do you have a `$` in front?

Comment: I'd guess the $ is intended to be the command prompt?

Comment: The $ or # is a "common" convention to indicate the prompt. It's also a way to prevent lusers from copy-pasting something dumb, maybe.

Comment: The $ to prevent users copy/pasting something dumb is more of an annoyance to the people trying to double click to get the command than it saves dumb people. They'll just remove the "$" anyway. Also, isn't giving them the command the whole point in the first place? Sure if the command is delete 10000 dirs etc

Answer (score 8):

You can definitely do that (with the adjustments the others mentioned like `sudo sh /pathto/script.sh` or `./script.sh`).  However, I do one of a few things to run them system wide to not worry about dirs and save me useless extra typing.

1) Symlink to `/usr/bin`

```
ln -s /home/username/Scripts/name.sh /usr/bin/name
```

(be sure there is no overlapping name there, because you would obviously override it.)  This also lets me keep them in my development folders so I can adjust as necessary.

2) Add the Scripts dir to your path (using .bash_profile - or whatever.profile you have on your shell)

`PATH=/path/to/scripts/:$PATH`

3) Create Alias's in the `.bash_profile`  in `~/.bash_profile` add something like:

```
alias l="ls -l"
```

As you can tell, the syntax is just alias, digits you want to act as a command, the command.  So typing "l" anywhere in the terminal would result in `ls -l`  If you want sudo, just `alias sl="sudo ls -l"` to note to yourself l vs sl (as a useless example).

Either way, you can just type `sudo nameofscript` and be on your way.  No need to mess with ./ or . or sh, etc.  Just mark them as executable first :D

Comment: I would highly recommand option 2.

Comment: Why?, it's a best practice or just taste?

Answer (score 6):

I usually do like you say

```
sh /path/to/script
```

And to run it as root/superuser

```
sudo sh /path/to/script
```

Your current directory only matters if the scripts assumes you are in the same folder as it. I would assume most scripts don't do this and you are save to run it like above.

Comment: would not work if secure_path is set in /etc/sudoers file

Comment: this seems like the most straightforward method.  also, `perl /path/to/script` for perl scripts (since he mentioned perl).

Answer (score 4):

I usually keep my scripts in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/sbin/` (if the script needs root privileges) where, according to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS), they belong.

All you have to do is to make sure these two directories are added to your `PATH`. You can do this by editing your `$HOME/.bashrc` file and adding this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

If you want to be able to execute a script as root via `sudo`, you have to add these directories to the variable `secure_path` in your `/etc/sudoers`.

```
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Editing this file is done by running `visudo` which ensures you don't have any mistakes.

Comment: Typo: you mean `.bashrc` instead of `.bachrc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have scripts lying around that you need to run often, and they depend on their location for finding resources you can easily do this by just combining commands in an alias like this.

```
alias run-script="cd /home/user/path/to/script/ && bash script.sh"
```

This way you don't have to alter anything else to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why no one has suggested this one, but it's super easy! I've Googled a few times and couldn't find this exact answer I'm giving so I'd thought I'd share. IMO, this but the best solution, also the easiest one, for me anyway, however others may feel and do things differently.

```
# Place this somewhere in your .bashrc/.bash_profile/etc and edit as you see fit

YOURCOMMAND () {
  cd /path/to/directory/containing/your/script/ && ./YOURSCRIPT
}
```

First the 'cd' command telling it the directory of the scripts location. Then '&&' so that you can tie it after excuting the next command. Finally open your script just as you would would execute it within terminal! Saved your in your BASH file and takes 5 seconds to setup.

Hope this helped someone.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to run `./script` and the path is `/home/test/stuff/`

But the path you're currently in is `/home/test/public_html/a/`

Then you would need to do `../../stuff/./script`

Which goes back 2 folders, then into into the folder there and run the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it works like this in linux, assuming it doesn't if no-ones suggested it.  But instead of using ././ to go back directories.  Can you use quotes to give it an absolute path?  Maybe it doesn't give you access to the whole drive to even be able to do that actually come to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to modify your script to use its absolute path before addressing any relative files.

Of course for scripts we can do it conveniently and flexibly by keeping the [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) of the script in a variable before-hand.

For example, change:

```
cat needed_file
```

to:

```
SCRIPT_PATH=$(dirname "$0")
cat "${SCRIPT_PATH}/needed_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

just run  " sh + path "

`sh /Desktop/Foldername/ExecutableFile`   *or*
`./Desktop/foldername/Executable File`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please see [how to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and [formatting](https://superuser.com/editing-help). Code and commands are marked with the code brackets `{}` on the edit box toolbar, or enclosed in backticks. Also when answering an old question the new answer should bring something previously not suggested. This is already suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/510156/330527). Please check the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), Asking and Answering in [Help]((https://superuser.com/help) and some q:s with accepted answers to learn how the site works.

Answer (score -1):

Ancient question, but a timeless one.

The solution I've consistently seen is to have a `$HOME/bin` directory and put it first in `$PATH` (via `~/.bashrc` if it isn't already there; on some systems `~/bin` is first in `$PATH` by default). Dropping scripts in there for execution or symlinks to scripts/executables elsewhere is the simple way to deal with path issues that shouldn't affect the system or other users.

If a script requires additional resources that can be found *relative to its own location* (not uncommon) then the envvar `$BASH_SOURCE` is used. `$BASH_SOURCE` always contains the absolute path to the currently running script itself, regardless the value of `$PWD`.

Consider the following:

```
ceverett@burrito:~$ echo $PATH
/home/ceverett/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

So we can see that `$HOME/bin` is first in `$PATH`, so whatever I put in `~/bin` will run. I have a demonstration script called `~/bin/findme`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running from $BASH_SOURCE"
```

This can be used to get the absolute path to the running script's location.

```
ceverett@burrito:~$ findme
Running from /home/ceverett/bin/findme
ceverett@burrito:~$ cd foo
ceverett@burrito:~/foo$ findme
Running from /home/ceverett/bin/findme
ceverett@burrito:~/foo$ cd /
ceverett@burrito:/$ findme
Running from /home/ceverett/bin/findme
```

Comment: (1) While this appears to be useful information, the question didn’t ask how to ***write*** scripts that use resources relative to their own location; it asked about running scripts. (2) I’m not sure how your second paragraph addresses the question.  Are you suggesting that, if I write a script and Desmond wants to run it, he should link it into his private `bin` directory?  That seems cumbersome.  (3) Also, it breaks location independence.  If `/home/desmond/bin/foo` is a link to my script, then `BASH_SOURCE` will be `/home/desmond/bin/foo`, and the script won’t be able to find its resources.

Comment: @G-Man (1) The user didn't provide much context. Whenever this question has been asked of me over the last 30 years it has always been in the context a user (usually a new sysop or developer) running a mix of his own and other acquired scripts to automate trivial tasks, so I answered it that way. This *does* assume a bit of scripting knowledge on the part of the user asking. (2) System-wide scripts are usually installed in `/bin` or a known location in `/opt`. (3) Location independence is exactly what this preserves when writing an inter-dependent collection of personal scripts.